# Proper filter to format date based on settings

Tags: wordpress

I query for comments by **get_comments(...)** function which returns array of **WP_Comment** objects. Now I want print submit date based on settings base format.

Which filter is appropriate to do that?

```
foreach( $comments as $comment )
{
    // Print 23-09-2017 11:05:23,  I want: 23 september 2017
    printf('Date: %s', apply_filters('get_comment_time', $comment->comment_date));
}
```

Format setting in config is good, because when I'am in **loop** (completely different place in code), I get proper format:

```
// get 23 september 2017
printf('<header><time>%s</time></header>', get_comment_date());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's turn out I need **mysql2date** and **get_option**:

```
foreach( $comments as $comment )
{
    printf('Date: %s',  mysql2date(get_option('date_format'), $comment->comment_date));
}
```

I found answer in source code of WordPress:

https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/0eecbf8bafbffb720ff365d03490a2de2aada8e8/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L539:

```
function get_comment_date( $d = '', $comment_ID = 0 ) {
    $comment = get_comment( $comment_ID );
    if ( '' == $d )
        $date = mysql2date(get_option('date_format'), $comment->comment_date);
    else
        $date = mysql2date($d, $comment->comment_date);

    return apply_filters( 'get_comment_date', $date, $d, $comment );
}
```